# Как создать массив из 3 студентов и вывести информацию о них?

Tags: java

Нужно создать массив из 3 студентов и реализовать метод, который выводит имя, возраст и курс студентов в консоль.

```java
public class Teacher {

    String name;
    int group;
    int age;

    public Teacher (String name, int age, int group) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.group = group;

        Student[] students = new Student[3];

        students[0] = new Student("Мария");
        students[1] = new Student("Николай");
        students[2] = new Student("Дмитрий");
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Пока что вы создали класс учителя/преподавателя с возрастом и группой -- это так и задумывалось?  Откуда должны студенты брать информацию о возрасте?

Comment: Да, я создал класс исходя из условия.

Comment: У вас какое-то странное условие.  К тому же, _локальный_ массив студентов в конструкторе учителя будет потерян, как только конструктор завершит своё выполнение.  Создание такого массива вполне бессмысленно.

Comment: А что у вас не получается? Отвечающий за вас должен создать массив студентов и реализовать метод?

Answer (score -2):

```
Student[] students = new Student[3];
students[0] = new Student("Мария", 21, 1);
students[1] = new Student("Николай", 18, 2);
students[2] = new Student("Дмитрий", 18, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    students[i].print();
}
```

Comment: `students[i].print();` - это что?

Comment: Метод вашего класса Studenr

Comment: 1) Я не автор вопроса =). 2) В коде в вопросе нет метода print() 3) лучше не `i < 3`, а `i < students.length`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]